# Mobile Game with Unity - Plugin for In-App Purchase

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm developing a mobile game with Unity and while it's very easy to get the core game loop running I have been having some problems with the interfaces to mobile devices and specifically with the In-App Purchasing functionality provided by Apple and Google. I heard that there are plugins who can help with that. Is there any place that lists all the options and can allow me to easily compare them?

Comment: We were beta testing MobiShop (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636) and made it easy to create a new shop and test the purchases it in the unity editor , as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plugins in Unity are very complex to develop on your own. You are right to look for existing ones. Here is a quick comparison of the 4 leading options for IAP in Unity today.

***Prime 31 - Plugin for iOS and Android***

This plugin has been around for quite some time. [Prime 31](http://prime31.com/plugins) have made numerous plugins for Unity and two of them deal with In-App Purchasing. One of them is for Android and the other one for iOS. The plugin claims to take all the pain away from In-App Purchases. If you are planning to just sell one or two things in your game and launch only on one hardware platform this will be a great choice. Cost - $70 - one time fee for single OS. However, if you are building a game with coins the user can collect during game play and implement a store with different types of goods, you will have to work hard and also buy more plugins for different Mobile OS and for Tapjoy/W3i.

***SOOMLA - Open Source IAP Project***

The SOOMLA project created a cross platform framework for virtual goods and In-App Purchasing. This is a commUnity developed project that has been rapidly growing in popularity and has recently added support for Unity. The plugin is available for download with support for both iOS and Android as well as a balance management system and security functions to prevent users from hacking their way into upgrades. The plugin is completely free and open which gives you complete flexibility.

***SOOMLA - Store-Front Plugin***

This plugin is built on top of the Open source [IAP Unity](http://soom.la/iap-unity/) plugin but also includes the store-front component. It's the best solution for developers who are implementing a game that has coins and multiple virtual goods in the store. The store supports different good types like single-use, single-purchase and Equipable goods. It automatically triggers the purchase requests from within the store instead of the developer having to implement that on his own. There is a free trial to get started and then if you want to continue making more changes to the store you pay $29/month or you can keep using the same store for free.

***Roar Engine - as part of their platform***

This is a full solution to manage various aspects of the game remotely and it includes an in-app purchase plugin as part of it. It might be an over kill and the cost can get to a few hundred dollars depending on the amount of active users.

Comment: Prime31 can be such a pain when you have got a trouble setting up one of their plugin. I used one of their plugin once, and I won't make the same mistake. You have other companies around, I for example like Unibill for the in-app plugin, with the Amazon Store/IOS/Android all-in-one, and they answered to all my queries. Hope this helps.

Comment: The Prime31 can be problematic at times.

Answer (score 2):

Unibill has been mentioned in a comment and, as its author, I would like to raise it as an option too.

It now supports 5 different billing platforms; iOS, Google Play, Amazon, Windows Phone 8 and the Mac App store.

If you're targeting multiple platforms (which is presumably why you're using Unity) then Unibill can save you a lot of time. Just check out some of our [Asset store reviews](http://u3d.as/content/outline-games/unibill/45P).

Comment: Can you take a look at this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555013/unity-unibill-plugin-issue-with-amazon-testing-amazonappstore-getitemdatareques

Answer (score 1):

After long looking for any usable free solution I just recently stumbled upon [OpenIAB](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/tree/master/unity_plugin) which supports all flavours of **android** stores right now but is soon to release support for **iOS** too!

[OpenIAB on Github](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/tree/master/unity_plugin)

Comment: The project/link is dead.

Comment: the new location is https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own plugins is not that hard. In android you will need to understand how `JNI` works.

If you don't want to waste time coding the IAP code, just get one of the existing plugins.
In my particular case, I have used Prime 31 plugins. They work just fine.

Comment: I researched a bit about JNI and found this post - http://www.koushikdutta.com/2009/01/jni-in-android-and-foreword-of-why-jni.html